# How can I generate ascii "graphical output" from R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I believe R can generate **stem-and-leaf for ascii histograms**, and **scatter plots** using [this code from Matt Shotwell](http://www.r-bloggers.com/ascii-scatterplots-in-r/).

Can it also generate **ASCII based line graphs**, like this from [GNUPlot](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~vrable/gnuplot/using-gnuplot.html)?

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should look at the fairly recent [txtplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/txtplot/) package. Currently, it includes scatterplot, line plot,  density plot, acf, and bar chart.

From the online help,

```
> txtplot(cars[,1], cars[,2])
    +----+------------+------------+-----------+------------+--+
120 +                                                     *    +
    |                                                          |
100 +                                                          +
    |                                                     * *  |
 80 +                           *         *                    +
    |                                        *       *    *    |
 60 +                           *              *               +
    |                              *    * *    *       *       |
 40 +                         *      *  * *  *                 +
    |                 *       * *    *  *    * *               |
 20 +         *       *  * *  * *  *                           +
    |            *    *  * *                                   |
    |  *      *    *                                           |
  0 +----+------------+------------+-----------+------------+--+
         5           10           15          20           25
```

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. However looks like the main function txtplot() can only handle 1 data series. I'd like to be able to plot 2 sets of data.

Comment: With the example shown above, you can play with the `pch` argument, e.g. `txtplot(cars[,1], cars[,2], pch=letters[1:2])`. This assumes that you arrange your x and y accordingly (alternating, or stacking). I can show an example, but I think it is fairly basic and you got the idea.

Answer (score 8):

I know there is support for basic interaction between R and GnuPlot in the [TeachingDemos](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TeachingDemos/) package. Perhaps that can achieve what you want.