# Text Based Graphs in R

Tags: r, graph

When doing analysis I like to output all my tables and results to a text file. I do many graphs to plot the lift from models and was wondering if it was possible to output graphs as ascii text graphic so they can be output to my text file.

Comment: Text as in postscript or ascii art? Or?

Comment: There's a package that does basic text based graphs (boxplot, scatter etc) that I came across a month ago but had no use for and can't seem to find it now.

Comment: Could you show us an example? It's still a bit ambiguous as to what you're looking for.

Comment: @mdsumner Text as in ascii art.

Comment: Put that in the q to make it clearer.

Comment: Updated as suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the `txtplot` package, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9151960/567015

Comment: That's the one I was thinking of, though it doesn't appear to offer boxplots.

Comment: @Sacha - txtplot is very very close to what I seek. I just want something with the ability to do line graphs. I'll use it in the mean time. I don't have enough reputation points to vote you up but if a better alternative is not presented I'll give you credit for the answer.

Comment: @Sacha - playing with the number of `*` in the `pch` parameter allowed me to get workable output. I used `pch='******'` to give me the ability to see the parter. I'm giving you credit for the answer. I hope it doesn't deter others from posting additional options. Thank you.