# How can I get R to plot something in Unix terminal

Tags: r, unix

I'm running R from Unix and would like to see all output without any pop-ups. So, for example, if in unix I run

```
R -f test.r
```

Where test.r is

```
value = pnorm(rnorm(10000))
hist(value,breaks=10)
```

I would like the output to include a histogram drawn in the terminal. Is this possible? I'm assuming I need some kind of Unix plotting package.

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9151960/1201032

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I generate ascii "graphical output" from R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151884/how-can-i-generate-ascii-graphical-output-from-r)

Answer (score 5):

There is [txtplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/txtplot/) package. Here is an example from the manual on how to output a histogram:

```
## text based barchart
x <- factor(c("orange", "orange", "red", "green", "green", "red", "yellow", "purple", "purple", orange"))
txtbarchart(x)
```

If you need more complex plots I would recommend you take a look at [gnuplot](http://gnuplot.info/) and [Rgnuplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rgnuplot) package that allows to call it from R. gnuplot has "dumb" terminal type which outputs ascii graphics.